# Every Activity in Android is a Process,or One Application is one process

Tags: android, process, android-activity, ipc

In this page, http://androidapps.org.ua/androidintro_ipc.html , intent switching between activities is described as Inter Process Communication. Now  I am confused whether every activity is a separate process in android or All activities inside an application is one process. I have checked the process id of all activities and service in my Application using:

```
 int id = android.os.Process.myPid();
 System.out.println("Process id of Activity1 :"+id);
```

But it is showing same process id.
Please reply back.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
All activities inside an application run in one process?
```

It depends on value of `android:process` attribute in application manifest.

if attribute `android:process` is not defined for Application/Activity tags in the manifest, by default all the activities will run in single process (process name will be name of the package defined in manifest)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.so.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity3">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In the above manifest all activities run in process `com.so.test`,ps command output in adb shell:

```
# ps
app_39    668   33    84492  20672 ffffffff afd0c51c S com.so.test
```

If `android:process` is specified for Activity new process will be created with the same userid and the activity runs in that process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.so.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:process="com.so.p1">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:process="com.so.p2">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity3" android:process="com.so.p3">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If the manifest is defined like above

```
Activity1 runs in com.so.p1 process
Activity2 runs in com.so.p2 process
Activity3 runs in com.so.p3 process
```

ps output in adb shell

```
# ps
app_39    650   33    83192  20900 ffffffff afd0c51c S com.so.p1
app_39    659   33    83188  20864 ffffffff afd0c51c S com.so.p2
app_39    668   33    84492  20672 ffffffff afd0c51c S com.so.p3
```

If an Activity needs to be run in another process not defined in this manifest, both APKs should be signed with the same certificate.

Comment: Activity1 runs in com.so.p1 process
Activity2 runs in com.so.p2 process
Activity3 runs in com.so.p3 process Will each process run in separate VM ? How it is encapsulated to that application ?

Comment: How about the service, broadcast are they each run in a separate process or the same as activity (i.e 3 processess)?

Comment: Note that local broadcasts do not work between different processes.

Answer (score 5):

No the activities of one application don't run on a different process each. And actually, even different applications built by the same developer (if the same certificate is used for all applications) could run in the same process!

[As the documentation says:](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

> Application modularity – The Android
>   system allows applications that are
>   signed by the same certificate to run
>   in the same process, if the
>   applications so requests, so that the
>   system treats them as a single
>   application. In this way you can
>   deploy your application in modules,
>   and users can update each of the
>   modules independently if needed.

Comment: So if the scenario is like this:The four Application component(Activity,Service,Content Provider,Broadcast Receiver) runs in separate thread under one process . The thread of Activity is the main UI thread, if any changes done in other thread, it have to inform the main UI thread.

Comment: @Naba: "The four Application component(Activity,Service,Content Provider,Broadcast Receiver) runs in separate thread under one process" -- no. There is one process, but they all share the main application thread.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to use [multi-processing][1] application approach using Manifest component element with `android:process` attribute. It is applied for all components

```
<application>
    <activity/>
    <service/>
    <receiver/>
    <provider/>
</application>
```

Additionally `<application>` element also supports an `android:process` attribute, to set a default value that applies to all components.

By default a `component` `process name` is a package name. It can be overrode by `<application>` or `<android component>(the biggest priority)` element

Please note that each app process has is **own** Application instance. As a result if you define your own custom application class (`<application android:name=".CustomApplication" ...>`) be ready that at least `Application.onCreate()` will be called every time during creating a new process.

JFYI, please note that `ContentProvider.onCreate()` is called before any other inits like `Application.onCreate()` etc. It can be helpful to get a `Context` for your library without extra code from dev side

To get process name you can use the next method

```
@Nullable
public static String getProcessName(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
        if (processInfo.pid == android.os.Process.myPid()) {
            return processInfo.processName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or via `Terminal` enter `adb shell ps | grep <packagename>`
[1]: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes

Answer (score 0):

You can send an intent to another application, provided it has an intent-filter.

So yes all of your activities in your application will run in the same process.

For eg: You can send a generic intent to all email applications. Gmail is one such application that has a intent filter which listens to the email intent. This is how you achieve IPC using intents.

Comment: So if the scenario is like this:The four Application component(Activity,Service,Content Provider,Broadcast Receiver) runs in separate thread under one process . The thread of Activity is the main UI thread, if any changes done in other thread, it have to inform the main UI thread