# Two Processes exist in One Android Application. Really?

Tags: android, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can an Android application have more than one process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567768/how-can-an-android-application-have-more-than-one-process)

It's painful for me to get the answer. 
Is it possible to have more than one processes in one Android application? Anyone could help me? Would you please give me an example? How could we implemente two processes in one Android application?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are talking about threads? [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567768/how-can-an-android-application-have-more-than-one-process and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468126/every-activity-in-android-is-a-process-or-one-application-is-one-process

Comment: It's not about thread. But the links you gave to me is pretty good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
For example look at the SERVICE class.

```
android:process = "String" The name of the process where the service is to run.
```

This starts the service in separate process

Comment: Yes, it's right. I also got it from google android website. And this is not about threads. But I don't know the advantage of such a method compared with multithread...