# How do I catch content provider initialize?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

As we know content provider loads on application run. But I want to make some operations before content provider will launch. How do I catch this operation? Before content provider's onCreate method would be called

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think Ive found solution. Ive created my custom application class and overridden  attachBaseContext method

```
<application android:name=".ApplicationController" ...>
```

---

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        // some of your own operations before content provider will launch
    }
}
```

Comment: That may work at the moment, but I do not know if it will be reliable across versions.

Comment: Its survived across 17 apis )) Maybe in the feature google will provide us any apis for this operation, but for now it works. Thank you for reply!

Comment: This solution works, however it's not fully functional. For instance, the `Context.getMainLooper()` method returns `null` when called before `Application.onCreate()`.

Comment: Be carefully: in this method `getApplicationContext()` will also return `null`, because the `Application.onCreate()` is not called yet.

Answer (score 4):

My solution requires use of the `call(Uri, String, String, Bundle)` API (so, it's not fully backward-compatible). But I have the stuff that I want the `ContentProvider` to prepare before it is used in my override of that `call` method. Then I do `getContentResolver().call(BASE_URI, METHOD, null, Bundle.EMPTY)` in my `Application.onCreate()`. Essentially, it defers that stuff until after my `Application` is being created, which is what we expected the `ContentProvider`'s `onCreate` to be doing naturally.